# differences between rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can you explain to me what are differences between these rewrite rules?

```
rewriterule ^news/category/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?p=news&category=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
rewriterule ^news/category/(.+)/([0-9]+)/*$    index.php?p=news&category=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

differences between `(.*)` and `(.+)` and differences between `/?$` and `/*$` ?

and

```
rewriterule ^news/category/(.*)/?$    index.php?p=news&category=$1 [L,QSA]
rewriterule ^news/category/(.+?)/*$    index.php?p=news&category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

differences between `(.*)` and `(.+?)` ?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have the technical answer from Gert.
My "non-technical" is:

- line #1: if the URL has a string *or nothing*, followed by a slash and a number *or nothing*, ending with `/` *or not*, then apply the rewriterule
- line #2: if the URL has a string, followed by a slash and a number *or nothing*, ending with *whatever*, then apply the rewriterule

Here are the URL problems you can have:

- with #1, this will be considered "valid": `news/category//548/`.
- with #2, this will be considered "valid": `news/category/whatever/548/this-is-a-problematic564string`.

You can apply the same principle to your second comparison/question.

Answer (score 0):

`(.*)` Matches between **zero** and unlimited times, as **many times** as possible giving back as needed (greedy)
`(.+)` Matches between **one** and unlimited times, as **many times** as possible giving back as needed (greedy)
`(.+?)` Matches between **one** and unlimited times, as **few times** as possible expanding as needed (lazy)

Go to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) for debugging of your regex

the `/?$` and `/*$` I'm not sure. It always matches.